# #container shifts to the left after third #btnAdd click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have no idea why this happens, but after clicking `#btnAdd` for the third time and adding the third set of form elements, the entire `#container` structure moves slightly to the left.

Here's my JSBin (JsFiddle is down): http://jsbin.com/enowiv/edit#javascript,html

Does anyone know why this is?

Comments, thoughts and of course, answers would be greatly appreciated :)!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the vertical scrollbar is showing on the third click.

You can get it to always show by using the CSS:

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ;). Any would setting `overflow: hidden` to either `body` or `#container` help remove the shift?

Comment: Added `overflow: hidden` to `body` which worked perfectly. I'll accept your answer after the timer goes, thanks a lot :) :)!

Comment: @Pixelatron: Using `overflow:hidden` is weird? You're stopping the user from being able to scroll down to see the hidden content?

Comment: @Pixelatron: Changing your `#container` CSS to be `margin: 10% auto 0 auto;` would be a better solution.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot more sense, sorry a bit tired. I usually declare all four `margin:` values, hence why I was a bit thrown off by this in the first place.